# Sorting Virtual/Created Column in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, columnsorting, interactive-grid

I'm not quite sure whether the description for the column I'm working on is proper, so bear with me.

I got an Interactive Grid that I'm adapting, and it's supposed to work such as this:

It should select a name on the first column (an autocomplete field), followed by 3 columns, each with a checkbox. I need to order the data in the grid by the name in the first column. Problem is, I can't use an "order by" in the select statement, so I need to use APEX's "Column sorting".
The column for the name, however, isn't shown in the list to select the order by value. I only get the 3 checkboxes as an option to order it.

I tried having a copy of the name column, but this time, hidden (and not an autocomplete field), but it doesn't work either. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

The IG will only allow you to sort by columns that have been enabled for sorting. By default, only columns of certain data types and maximum lengths are enabled for sorting, but you can override this for each column in your IG definition.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! I ended up finding a workaround, due to the structure of the query. In short, the auto complete field is a concatenation of two values, the first of them being stored in the table from which I'm mainly selecting. It's the same value that the 3 checkboxes have hidden in them (which are checkboxes via cases in the query), and they themselves are selected through union, and because the table will always have one of those boxes filled, I will always have one of those values being selected and put into the auto complete field. Sounds a bit crazy, but it's working now.